# Conversion of .tsx files into .js file in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tsx

I am learning React JS. The problem I am facing is that I have bundle of files in .tsx extension so the situation is I want to convert my .tsx files into .js extension for the betterment of my project. And also, when I'll start the project on browser side and so after compilation It should load the .js files on browser side after compilation. I am using React JS, Typescript and Vite JS for front-end tool.

I am working Ubuntu 18.04

> node.js version == 14.20.0

> npm version == 6.14.7

and here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

Kindly help me to resolve this issue:

Comment: If you’re new to TS, TSX, or JS in general, I’d HIGHLY recommend you use https://parceljs.org/ to bundle your app. It’s by far the easiest one to set-up as it usually doesn’t even need a config. It’s perfect for trying out new things and quickly prototyping some practice apps

Comment: Otherwise, for react itself, you should probably start with either https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started or (if you want both frontend and backend) https://blitzjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use tyescript compiler for converting the tsx in js.

```
npx -p typescript tsc somefile.tsx
```

Comment: sir, thank you for your answer. I have mentioned above that it is not a single file its a complete project. and also you plz define that how to run .js files after compilation